Unity AR replace ARPlane with GameObject prefab
I am looking to replace the area of the ARPlane with an 3D Plane. ARMeshVisualizer does this really well but I need to have an actual 3D object there instead of the mesh so I can use an ARAnchor (very important) on it.
I have tried something like this but had no luck
void PlaceObjectOnPlane(ARPlane plane)
    {
        Vector3 position = plane.center;
        Quaternion rotation = plane.transform.rotation;

        Vector2 planeSize = plane.size;
        Vector3 objectScale = new Vector3(planeSize.x, 1f, planeSize.y); 
        
        if (objectToPlace != null && !objectToPlace.activeInHierarchy)
        {
            objectToPlace.SetActive(true);
            objectToPlace.transform.position = position;
            objectToPlace.transform.rotation = rotation;
            objectToPlace.transform.localScale = objectScale;
        }

    }

Thanks

I have tried something like this but had no luck .. what exactly does this mean? What did you expect to happen? What happened instead?

@derHugo It did not scale properly and or conform to the points generated by the Mesh. They use a triangle kind of method in ARMeshVisualizer but I could not replicate it correctly. I also tried to calculate the rows and cols and place small 3D Cubes but they would stack on each other and only cover the x-axis

You need to edit your question to provide more context and details. As is, we don’t have enough information to help.
